# Use bound variables in LIKE query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-like

just going through my site and testing the forms for sql vulnerabilities and forgot i hadn't get converted my search query to use bound variables.

The addon for firefox (Sql Inject Me) is excellent! On a side note, are there any more add ons i can use that will check for security issues, loops holes etc?

So now for the question, how do i convert this:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE frontpage = 1 && (tags LIKE '%".$searchterm."%' OR blogtitle LIKE '%".$searchterm."%') ORDER BY id DESC";

try 
{ 
    // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $countresults = $stmt->rowCount();

} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{ 
    // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
    // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
}
```

So i can use :searchterm etc. I know how to do this query on simple SELECTs etc, just not sure how to do it for the LIKE query.

Comment: @zerkms im not sure where to place the :variable in the query?

I have tried it as LIKE '%:variable%' but no results.

Comment: `$variable = '%value%';` then `LIKE :variable`

Comment: the one way i didnt think would work so didnt try it haha. Thanks for the help :)